# Как преобразовать объект к обобщению?

Tags: java

Не знаю правильно ли поставлен вопрос, но по коду будет видно в чём его суть. Есть класс, использующий обобщение.

```
public abstract class TypeAdapter<T> {

    public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            out.nullValue();
        } else {
            TypeAdapter.this.write(out, value);
        }
    }

    public abstract void write(JsonWriter jsonWriter, T t) throws IOException;
}
```

Пытаюсь воспользоваться данным классом:

```
public void toJson(Object src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonWriter writer) throws JsonIOException {
    TypeAdapter<?> adapter = getAdapter(TypeToken.get(typeOfSrc));
    try {
        adapter.write(writer, src); //Вот здесь компилятор ругается. Как - смотрите ниже.
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new JsonIOException(e);
    } 
}
```

Как ругается: пишет, что ожидает '?', а получает java.lang.Object. Но ведь '?' - это просто абстракция, демонстрирующая, что непонятно какой тип будет на этапе объявления переменной. По сути, тип будет понятен только в рантайме. К тому же, что может быть более абстрактней java.lang.Object? Как пыталась решить эту проблему:

```
TypeAdapter<src.getClass()> adapter = getAdapter(TypeToken.get(typeOfSrc));
```

Но, видимо, нельзя так в Java. Как устранить эту ошибку?

Comment: ? - это не абстракция!!! Он говорит вам о том, что будет передан тип  Object либо его наследник

Comment: @Санаев, почему тогда компилятор не принимает Object?

Comment: Где Вы увидели, чтобы дженерики использовались подобным образом: `TypeAdapter<?> adapter = ...` и `TypeAdapter<src.getClass()>`? Все пользуются так: `TypeAdapter<Type>`, где _Type_ - это **конкретный ссылочный тип**. Например, `TypeAdapter<String>`, `TypeAdapter<Object>`.

Comment: @notaProgrammer , https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/Gson.java 695-я строка, например. Исходный код от Google.

Comment: @notaProgrammer, хах ... в своём комментарии похоже нашла решение проблемы)

Comment: @J.Huxley, это хорошо, что нашла))) Но я бы, пожалуй, сказал, что так писать "не хорошо". `TypeAdapter<src.getClass()>` - а вот так тем более. Такой код к ясности не ведет. Хотя это мое мнение. Все же я не программист)))